# Setting up remote Git repo on Tomcat

Tags: git, http, tomcat, webserver

I need to setup a remote Git repository that will communicate via http. All the stuff I've read on the web refers to setup using Apache web server. I'd rather use Tomcat. Is that possible? Is it advisable?

If yes, I'd really appreciate advice on how to go about doing it. If no, what other options are there?

Thanks

Comment: So... where Apache is a server of static web resources, Tomcat is a web application server.  Of course you could create a web application that does nothing but serve static resources.  If that statement of the problem, plus the docs you found for Apache setup, isn't enough to get you set up, then I would suggest you think twice about why you want to configure (and then have to maintain) such an uncommon arrangement.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget you have other alternatives, which don't involve Tomcat (or java, or anything actually)

For instance: [Gitea](https://gitea.io/en-us/)

The full setup is:

- copy the right executable for your platform from [`go-gitea/gitea` v1.2.0-rc1](https://github.com/go-gitea/gitea/releases/tag/v1.2.0-rc1)
- launch it with `gitea -web`

That is it: instant web server for cloning (and [so much more](https://docs.gitea.io/en-us/)).
And instant website (see [try.gitea.io/explore/repos](https://try.gitea.io/explore/repos) as an online example)